# How to set gis_enable to True

Tags: django, geodjango

I have a geoDjango setup with postgresql/postgis and everything works fine.

Now I try to install django-raster but it fails on migration.

The error is

> Raster fields require backends with raster support.

It happens because connection.features.gis_enabled is set to False

in site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py

How to set it to True ?

Answer (score 1):

My initial setup was actually wrong, I had to use

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
         ...
     }
}
```

instead of

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
         ...
     }
}
```